# Marsilio Ficino' commentary on the Symposium on Love guidance

Tags: ethics, reference-request, plato, ancient-philosophy, love

Is Marsilio Ficino's commentary on the Symposium on Love a good book to read alongside the Symposium for someone who is reading the Platonic dialogue?

Does it give a good understanding of the Symposium that isn't too focused on the Christian ideas of love? I want a commentary that talks about the Symposium from a "general" perspective amongst scholars?

Also is Ficino's commentary good to read on its own after the dialogue to get a broader understanding of the notions of, platonic or not, the philosophy of love and friendship?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See [Marsilio Ficino](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ficino/): "Ficino authored commentaries on and summaries of Plato's writings, many of which he continued to work on for the rest of his career; these included the Timaeus, Phaedrus, *Symposium* (less a commentary and more of a free-standing dialogue), and the Philebus."

Comment: And also: "[Ficino’s commentary on the Symposium](http://www.iep.utm.edu/ficino/#H2) — an unorthodox dialogue itself loosely inspired by the original — became one of his most popular and influential treatments of Plato."

Answer (score 1):

**Plato and Ficino - agreement**

> Plato's Symposium and Ficino's Commentary agree in 'the vision of spiritual love as an ennobling force, in contrast
>    to carnal love, which debases, a vision which in Socrates' speech pro-
>    duces the famous description of a ladder of love leading up to the
>    pure idea of the good and the beautiful.' (Alan S. Trueblood, 'Plato's Symposium and Ficino's Commentary in Lope de Vega's Dorotea', Modern Language Notes, Vol. 73, No. 7 (Nov., 1958), pp. 506-514 : 507.)

**Plato and Ficino - divergence**

Ficino Christianises Plato : the spiritual love of which Plato talks in the Symposium is transformed, Christianised, by Ficino who 'broaden[s] it into a conception of love as the motive power of the universe.' (Trueblood, ibid.)

In more detail :

> In the Symposium of Plato Ficino found the
>    completion of the arc from God to man; for him the discussion of the
>    meaning of personal love in the Symposium completed the pattern. Just
>    as courtly love fitted into place at the end of the scale of Christianity, so
>    the Symposium fitted into place at the end of the scale of Platonism; the
>    pattern was complete, the two scales were really one, reaching from God
>    to man and from man to God. All the physical drives of human love
>    might be justified spiritually and at the same time idealized intellectually,
>    because love in man is not only a God-given and cosmically necessary
>    and irresistible search upwards toward a perfection which is both spiritual and intellectual; it is also an irresistible, God-given, and cosmically
>    necessary compulsion downward to create the likeness of Divine Beauty
>    in the physical world. Platonism and Christianity, seen as love, are one;
>    and the term "Platonic love," which Ficino invented, embraces love in its
>    widest sense. Love for Ficino is the dart in the eye and the fire in the
>    heart of the courtly lover, becoming idealized through the process described in the Symposium and ultimately revealing itself as identical
>    with the world force of Neoplatonic Christianity. All the known love traditions are fused to show how love between individual persons derives
>    from the love between the individual and God. (Sears Jayne, 'Ficino and the Platonism of the English Renaissance', Comparative Literature, Vol. 4, No. 3 (Summer, 1952), pp. 214-238 : 227-8.)

This interprets Plato's ideas and arguments in the Symposium beyond anything Plato himself would have recognised.

**Plato and Ficino - incompleteness**

> Jayne points out that Ficino's actual commentary is limited to only six
>    specific passages of Plato's dialogue; its main thrust consists rather in the
>    exposition of Ficino's ideas about love. Ficino's awareness of the dual nature
>    of his treatise is reflected in a disparity of titles: he called his 1474 Tuscan
>    version of the work Sopra lo amore and often called his original Latin treatise
>    simply De amore with no reference to "Commentary." (John C. Nelson, 'Commentary on Plato's Symposium on Love by Marsilio Ficino and
>   Sears Jayne',  Italica, Vol. 65, No. 2 (Summer, 1988), pp. 164-165 : 164.)

**Ficino - a good read ?**

Make up your own mind from the online text : https://www.scribd.com/doc/149506301/Marsilio-Ficino-s-Commentary-on-Plato-s-Symposium-Sears-Reynolds-Jayne-A-M

Page through the Introduction and the Latin text to find the English version.